# pure css focus on parent element and change styles on child element [CSS / SCSS]

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm wondering if there is a way if you focus on a parent element can you change the style of a child element without javascript so say I have

```
<li class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</li>
```

and I want to be able to change the style of both child elements if you focus on the parent element. So I tried to do this..

```
.parent{
   &:focus{
      & .child1{
         background: green;
      }
      & .child2{
         background: green;
      }
   }
}
```

but that doesn't seem to be working, now I know I could do this with javascript, but I'm just wondering if there is a pure CSS way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible, but you need to clarify and understand the term 'focus on an element'.

If you mean mouseover, aka hover, then you can update your SASS with `&:hover` to this:

```
.parent{
   &:hover{
      & .child1{
         background: green;
      }
      & .child2{
         background: green;
      }
   }
}
```

However, if you do mean an actual focus event then you need to know which elements can gain focus by default from a click or keyboard interaction.

`li` is not "focusable" by default but you can change this by adding `tabindex="0"` to it:

```
<li class="parent" tabindex="0">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</li>
```

`tabindex` should be used as little as possible as it can have bigger accessibility implications.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex